# how to generate such an image in Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I am thinking of process an image to generate [image: the following effect] in Mathematica given its powerful image processing capabilities. Could anyone give some idea as to how to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of course. You just have to make a little program for raytracing off-axis non-paraxial approximation lenses. Doable? yes. Useful? I doubt it. There are a lot of ray tracing software packages out there.

Comment: @belisarius is that really necessary? I think this could be well approximated with a calculated offset for the image in each cell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one version, using a textures.  It of course doesn't act as a real lens, just repeats portions of the image in an overlapping fashion.

```
t = CurrentImage[];

(* square off the image to avoid distortion *)
t = ImageCrop[t, {240,240}];

n = 20; 
Graphics[{Texture[t], 
   Table[
     Polygon[
       Table[h*{Sqrt[3]/2, 0} + (g - h)*{Sqrt[3]/4, 3/4} + {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, 
         {t, 0., 2*Pi - Pi/3, Pi/3}
         ], 
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> Transpose[{
         Rescale[
           (1/4)*Sqrt[3]*(g - h) + (Sqrt[3]*h)/2., 
           {-n/2, n/2}, 
           {0, 1}
           ] + {0, Sqrt[3]/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0, -(Sqrt[3]/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}/(n/2), 
         Rescale[
           (3.*(g - h))/4, 
           {-n/2, n/2}, 
           {0, 1}
           ] + {1, 1/2, -(1/2), -1, -(1/2), 1/2}/(n/2)
         }]
      ], 
      {h, -n, n, 2}, 
      {g, -n, n, 2}
    ]
  }, 
  PlotRange -> n/2 - 1
]
```

Here's the above code applied to the [standard image test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_test_image) ([Lena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna))

[image]

Comment: @Brett, +1 it looks great. But I only have Mma 7.0, which does not have `VertexTextureCoordinates` option. Cannot try it out. Is there a workaround or similar thing in Mma7.0? Thanks again!

Comment: I can, off the top of my head, think of two possibilities.  First, use something like `ParametricPlot` with a `ColorFunction` to draw the hexagons as a bunch of small polygons that are shaded from the texture image.  (This will be slow and memory-intensive if you want a decent resolution.)  Second, figure out a mapping from the hexagons to an `Image` and do your own discretization at some resolution.  Either method should work; you'll basically write a function to convert a single `Polygon` given information about the overall size of the result, and it'll take a bit of effort.  Good luck!

Comment: In case anyone doesn't know, Lena is available as `ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]` directly in Mathematica since version 6, IIRC. `ExampleData["TestImage"]` will list other test images, and `ExampleData[]` all the available kinds of... example data =)

Comment: @Michael The original Lena pics are much more inspirational than the example provided with Mma...

Answer (score 8):

"I think this could be well approximated with a calculated offset for the image in each cell" - Mr.Wizard

Exactly! As you can see from reconstructed image there is no lens effect and tiles are just displacements.

[image]

What you need is a [Hexagonal_tessellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tessellation) and a simple algorithm to calculate displacement for each hexagon from some chosen central point (weight/2, height/2).

Comment: +1 Nice reconstruction! The Hexagonal tessellation is exactly what Brett did in his answer. Btw - how did you obtain the reconstructed image?

Comment: @Ross yes, how exactly did you reconstruct it?

Comment: @Simon @acl - Gimp + Hand selection.

Comment: More scientific way is to split on tiles and use some feature matching.

Comment: @Ross said "Gimp + Hand selection." - very dedicated!

Comment: @Ross, if you are still around, you can see that there is interest in how you did this.  Please consider including an explanation.

Comment: I already explained this in my comment "Gimp + Hand selection"