# reconstruct the image in Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I posted [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272309/how-to-generate-such-an-image-in-mathematica) yesterday and it seems obviously that some people are interested in given the count of upvotes. But it does not seem to be very useful, as some Mathematica guru puts it. However, I think the reverse question is quite useful, i.e., how to reconstruct the original image in Mma. One answer given by [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198317/ross) actually used image processing software and did a decent job on reconstructing the original picture. It would be great to know how to **split on tiles and use some feature matching.** in Mma automatically.

Thank you all.

Comment: Would you like to close this question? Your original question has been answered now.

Answer (score 1):

Halfway there, posting on this old question just to see if someone wants to give it a try:

```
l = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3xte.jpg";
l1 = Binarize[GradientFilter[MeanShiftFilter[l, 3, .01, MaxIterations -> 10], 3] 
     // ImageAdjust, .1];
l2 = Erosion[Dilation[l1, 20], 20];
l3 = ImageData@ColorNegate@l2;
n = 1; While[l3[[1 ;; n, 1 ;; n]] == Array[1 &, {n, n}], n++];
ip = ImagePartition[l, n][[1, 1]];
ipMsft = MeanShiftFilter[ip, 3, .1, MaxIterations -> 100];
l8 = ColorNegate@GradientFilter[ ImageMultiply[ip, ipMsft], 6] // ImageAdjust;
ImageSubtract[l8, GradientFilter[l8, 1]]
```

[image]